# MySQL: A table having start_date and end_date: How to select one row for each day of a record?

Tags: mysql, select

one of my tables does have a start_date and end_date, both type DATE.
Usually, they are equal, but in some cases, end_date is bigger than the start date.
What I would like to achieve if possible is a SELECT which returns a ROW for each day.
So e.g. if start_date is 2018-06-28 and end date is 2018-06-30, the SELECT should return 3 rows for this record. My favourite way would be to change the start_date, like:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| id        | start_date |  end_date  |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|        45 | 2018-06-28 | 2018-06-30 |
|        45 | 2018-06-29 | 2018-06-30 | 
|        45 | 2018-06-30 | 2018-06-30 | 
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Could you give me a push into the right direction if this is possible? Searching for this didn't bring up anything useful.
Thanks a lot
Philipp

Comment: The simplest way would be to add a very basic "dates" table with every date, then join to it on `dates.date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date`. _Depending on your MySQL version, there could also be a more complicated "common table expression" (recursive) query possible._

Comment: This is awfully easy :) Especially since I already have a "day" table! Thanks for pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: Added as answer so you can close the question out.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to add a very basic "dates" table with every date, then join to it on dates.date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date.

*Depending on your MySQL version, there could also be a more complicated "common table expression" (recursive) query possible.*